# JS: Why does 2nd function not have stored value called?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to instantiate the first function with:

`let foo = first(22)`

this logs out `console.log(22, "value")` and `console.log(77, "newVal")`, respectively.

EDIT:

How do I execute the 2nd function in there?

```
 function first(value) {
    console.log(value, "value")
    let newVal = value + 55;
    console.log(indigo, "indigo")

    return function second(secondArgPassed) {
        return newVal + secondArgPassed
     }

 }

let foo = first(22);
foo(34)
```

Answer (score 1):

The second function is returned from the first function.

The return value of the first function is assigned to `foo`.

Thus: `foo()` or `foo(with, some, arguments)`.

> Why does 2nd function not have stored value called?

Because:

- You aren't calling it at all
- You have a variable named `newVal` defined as an argument to `second` which masks the variable named `newVal` that is declared with `let` in the wider scope of `first`.

Comment: so I don't need `newVal` as an argument to `second`?

Comment: That depends. Do you want to pass a value to it as an argument when you call `second`?

Comment: ideally, rather than just calling `( )`, I'd rather pass it an arg

Comment: Then pass it as an arg (that does make the whole idea of using a closure pointless though).

Comment: I just made an Edit and rewrote it above.  Does that rewrite make sense?  Isn't it still a closure since in addition to the new arg, it's still relying on `newVal` from the first func ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

The function you are calling first() has one parameter. Within the function you have created another function, which will do nothing, as you haven't called it. Also indigo is not defined.

```
function first(val){
 return val
}

function second(val){
 return val+22;
}

console.log(first(22));
console.log(second(55));
```

You could call this within the function with a check for the second paramter existing (in the example below it just needs to exist):

```
function first(val, newval){
 console.log(val, "value");
 if(!!newval){
 console.log(val+55,"value");
 }
}

first(22,22);

/* outputs:
"22","value"
"77","value"
*/
```

It would be worth reading up on javascript scope:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Your second() function is local to first() and is not getting called.